# Socket timeout not working in Rest template third party API call - Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate, response-time

I am trying to test response-time out by configuring socket time out when third party rest service call. I am calling external web service by Spring Rest Template in my service.

For response timeout testing purpose, the external web service is taking more time which I configured.

I have configured 1600 milliseconds for timeout, but unfortunately I am getting response in more then configured time, around 2500 - 3000 milliseconds.

As per the configuration I should get time out exception.

```
public ClientHttpRequestFactory getClientHttpRequestFactory(String timeout) {
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setConnectTimeout(Integer.parseInt(timeout))
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(Integer.parseInt(timeout))
            .setSocketTimeout(Integer.parseInt(timeout))
            .build();
    CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
            .build();
    return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(closeableHttpClient);
}
```

```
public String milisecTimeout = "1600";

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(appConfig.getClientHttpRequestFactory(milisecTimeout));
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpHeaders.set("Accept", "application/json");
        httpHeaders.set("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(request, httpHeaders);
        String responseBody = "";
try {
  ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(hostUrl, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity,  String.class);
  String statusCode = response.getStatusCodeValue();
  String responseBody = response.getBody();
  SearchRS searchSdnRS = objectMapper.readValue(responseBody, SearchRS.class);
} catch (Exception ex){
   log.error("Error:", ex.getCause());
}
```

Please correct me if any misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Socket timeout is defined as maximum time of inactivity between two data packets. It's not about total request duration. So in the case you're describing it could well be that the data transfer from server to client started after 1500 milliseconds and lasted 1000–1500 milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. 
For response time out(not total duration) what need to do, any configuration required.  Some time it was taking 80000 milliseconds.

Comment: For `RestTemplate` there is no out-of-the-box configuration available AFAIK. You could migrate to the more modern `WebClient` as it has the possibility to configure a [response timeout](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-timeout#1-response-timeout).